# In Node-js, render(ejsfile) not working unless and until I change its directory name from view to views

Tags: node.js, express

profile.ejs file name saved in view folder, and on every request it gave status code: 500 error. Just on changing the folder name from view to views, its start working. No server internal error, no invalid command error, don't know why?

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.get('/home',function(req, res){
 res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});
app.get('/profile/:name', function(req, res){
  res.render('profile');
});
app.listen(3000);
```

just changing the directory same code start working, explain please!
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Directory `views` is default directory of express template engine. After `app.set('view engine', 'ejs')`, Express will look for `(your-project-directory)/views` and set that directory as default.

---

If you don't want default behavior, you can specify the path to directory as your desire using:

```
app.set('views', 'path/to/your/template');
```

**For example:** If your want to name your directory `view` instead of `views`

```
app.set('views', './view');
```